# How to insert image array in following code ?

Tags: ios, arrays, image, gallery

I have download an Gallery sample code, but i don't know how to use it ? It shows 12 same pictures, and I want different pictures, I want an imagesArray instead of one picture, what should I do?

Following is my code,

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIViewAnimationExplose.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.allViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int numberColumn = 0;
    int numberRaw = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10 + numberColumn * 252, 10 + numberRaw * 248, 242, 238)];
        img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        img.clipsToBounds = YES;
        img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"becomeapanda_tumblr_com"];
        [self.view addSubview:img];

        [self.allViews addObject:img];

        numberColumn++;
        if (numberColumn > 2) {
            numberRaw++;
            numberColumn =0;
        }
    }

    self.exploseContainer = [[AnimationExploseContainer alloc] initWithViews:self.allViews];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename your images like img1,img2..... img12 and than modify your code like this,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10 + numberColumn * 252, 10 + numberRaw * 248, 242, 238)];
    img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    img.clipsToBounds = YES;
    img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%d",i]];
    [self.view addSubview:img];

    [self.allViews addObject:img];

    numberColumn++;
    if (numberColumn > 2) {
        numberRaw++;
        numberColumn =0;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello hello ，i have another problem now ,can you help me?tell me what should i do. in the 'Demo2ViewController.m' i dont want any storyboards or xibs ,because i need add it to my table view cell.please help me .thanks very much      http://code4app.com/down/7d5ac914125ca5420695dd999cf7f698/?id=51de1c296803faf95f000007

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on where you want to load your images from. The most simple is to add to your project and show those images. In this case:

1) You have to add your images to your project (File / Add Files to..)

2) Create an array of the image names, not less then 12

```
NSArray *my_image_names = @[@"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png",....<12 times>..];
```

3) modify code:

```
img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[my_image_names objectAtIndex:i]];
```